# Visualizing feature maps for VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tf2.3.0 and python3.6

Here is how I load the model

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_vgg():
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
    bn = layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)
    x = vgg16(bn)
    x = layers.Conv2D(256,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',name='conv2D',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
    flat_out = layers.Flatten()(x)
    h1 = layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='fc1',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(flat_out)
    h2 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(h1)
    h3 = layers.Dense(32,activation='relu',name='fc2',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(h2)
    h4 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(h3)
    new_out = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name='prediction')(h4)
    return keras.Model(inputs,new_out)

vgg = create_vgg()
vgg.load_weights('F:\\logs\\best_weight.h5')
vgg.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(5e-6),
            loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And I want to visualize all the feature maps of the 16 former layers:

```
output_layers = [layer.output for layer in vgg.layers[:16]]
activation_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg.input,outputs=output_layers)
```

I got an error while executing the last line:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

How can I fix this

Comment: This might be happening as a result of mismatch in sizes in the loaded weights or else your loaded weights might be missing some data regarding the weights

Comment: You have two input layers in your final model. You need to get rid of the input layer that comes with the pretrained vgg network and replace it with your own.